# Remove characters from a string and Filling NA values with the the values of the previous row

Tags: r, string

```
pic_names <- c("../img/pics/111L.jpg", NA, 
               "../img/pics/134L.jpg",NA, 
               "../img/pics/164L.jpg", NA, 
               "../img/pics/187L.jpg", NA)
df <- as.data.frame(pic_names)
```

I want to do two operations:

- Remove parts of the strings. The desired results is from "../img/pics/111L.jpg" to "111L"; from "../img/pics/134L.jpg" to "134L" and so on
- the NA cell has to be filled with the strings contained in the preceding rows. The output should like like this

pic_names 1      111L 2      111L 3      134L 4      134L 5      121R    6      121R 7      166R 8      166R

Comment: Unclear what you want

Comment: basenames(pic_names)

Comment: basename would work but does not remove the jpg

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! May I ask you also how would you transform "../img/amp/1OAR250.jpg" to "1OAR250" ? thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I would do

```
pic_names <- c("../img/pics/111L.jpg", NA, 
               "../img/pics/134L.jpg",NA, 
               "../img/pics/164L.jpg", NA, 
               "../img/pics/187L.jpg", NA)
df <- as.data.frame(pic_names)
# Load stringr package
library(stringr)
# Extract part of string that has numerics ended by character "L"
pics <- str_extract(pic_names, "[1-9]*L")
# Get the index of elements which are NAs
nas <- which(is.na(pics))
# Replace those with the previous value in the vector
pics[nas] <- pics[nas-1]
# print the vector
pics
```

EDIT:

So for other names some general regex stuff

```
[1-9]*
```

gives any any number of digits
Analogously

```
[a-z]*
```

and

```
[A-Z]*
```

for upper and lower case letters

So this should be possible

```
pics <- str_extract(pic_names, "[1-9]*[A-Z]*[1-9]*")
```

EDIT 2:
This should work for all files that do not have special characters in their names. The last part simply means "match this patern up to a dot".

```
picsAlt <- str_extract(basename(pic_names), "[A-Za-z0-9]*(?=.)")
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! May I ask you also how would you transform "../img/amp/1OAR250.jpg" to "1OAR250" ? thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
pic_names <- c("../img/pics/111L.jpg", NA, 
               "../img/pics/134L.jpg",NA, 
               "../img/pics/164L.jpg", NA, 
               "../img/pics/187L.jpg", NA)
df <- as.data.frame(pic_names, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$pic_names <- basename(df$pic_names)
df$pic_names <- gsub(".jpg", "", df$pic_names)

df$pic_names <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) 
  ifelse(is.na(df$pic_names[i]), df$pic_names[i-1], df$pic_names[i]))
```